# Skipping dates in ruby

Tags: ruby, date

I'm creating a program that will make the task of writing e-mail to users easier, however I need to figure out a way to skip over Saturday and Sunday, during our pending e-mail process the user is given 6 days to respond, so what I need is a way to for Ruby's `Date` class to skip Saturday and Sunday and keep an accurate count of 6 days excluding weekends.

For example:

```
require 'date'

date = Date.today
#=> #<Date: 2016-05-06 ((2457515j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
new_date = date + 6
#=> #<Date: 2016-05-12 ((2457521j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
new_date.strftime('%A')
#=> "Thursday"
date.strftime('%A')
#=> "Friday"
```

Obviously this example counts Saturday and Sunday, so how do I skip over these two days and also keep the count accurate?

Comment: you can check day using `date.strftime('%A')` if It is `Saturday` OR `Sunday` and then skip the task using if condition.

Comment: I'll give that a shot. However that wouldn't help with keeping the count accurate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a literal translation of your description of the requirement into Ruby:

```
require "date"

p today = Date.today
p (1..Float::INFINITY)
  .lazy
  .map { |offset| today + offset }
  .reject { |date| date.saturday? || date.sunday? }
  .drop(5)
  .next
```

The code creates a lazy enumeration of all days starting from tomorrow, rejects all Saturdays and Sundays, drops the next 5 valid candidates, and returns the next one.

Output:

```
#<Date: 2016-05-06 ((2457515j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
#<Date: 2016-05-16 ((2457525j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

A quick peek at the calendar shows that the output is correct.

Comment: That's very cool!  I wrote a script that implements the algorithm as a method, and prints out values to prove the results are correct.  It's at https://gist.github.com/keithrbennett/50598f478a6ad898ab3793f0d8b5052a.  Also, the upper bound does not have to be so high; 10 worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

You could implement something yourself by use of `Date#saturday?` and `Date#sunday?`

*Or*, you could use the [business time](https://github.com/bokmann/business_time) gem to handle all of this for you. After configuring it according to your needs (e.g. set the "working hours" to be from midnight-->midnight, if that's what you want), you can then do all sorts of things like:

```
6.business_days.after(Date.new(2014, 02, 7))
6.business_days.from_now
```

And so on.

Comment: That's a badass gem! Thanks for this!

Comment: I'm a little wary of gems that monkey patch core classes like number classes.  Is this gem very widely used and trusted?

Comment: Yes. VERY widely used. As you can imagine however, you need to be careful in how it's used. The biggest mistake I've seen is people writing unit tests that don't use BUSINESS hours -- and you end up with tests that "randomly" fail. (Actually, fail at particular times of day/week/month.) But this isn't a problem with the library itself; only in the way that it's used.

Answer (score 2):

You can use two methods [`saturday?`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-saturday-3F) and [`sunday?`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-sunday-3F)

```
>> require 'date'
=> true
>> d = Date.new(2016, 05, 3)
=> #<Date: 2016-05-03 ((2457512j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
>> d.saturday?
=> false
>> d.sunday?
=> false
>> a = d + 6
=> #<Date: 2016-05-09 ((2457518j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
>> a.saturday?
=> false
>> d = Date.today
=> #<Date: 2016-05-06 ((2457515j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
>> a = d + 1
=> #<Date: 2016-05-07 ((2457516j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
>> a.saturday?
=> true
```